# I need to make both of these buttons different colours

Tags: html, css

This is my code that I have tried various things to fix. Help would be much appreciated i am new to HTML & CSS

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    .dropbtn {
    background-color: #459b7a;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    }

    .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
      }

      .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      }

     .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

     .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

     .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #459b7a;}
     </style>
     </head>
     <body>


     <div class="dropdown">
     <button class="dropbtn">Family 2</button>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a value="http://www.">Victoria</a>
     <a value="http://www.">New South Wales</a>
     <a value="http://www.">Canberra</a>
     <a value="http://www.">Queensland</a>
     <a value="http://www.">Northern Territory</a>
      <a value="http://www.">Western Australia</a>
     <a value="http://www.">South Australia</a>
     </div>
     </div>

     </body>
     </html>
 
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <style>
     .dropbtn {
     background-color: #1375b9;
     color: white;
     padding: 20px;
     font-size: 16px;
     border: none;
     }

     .dropdown {
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
     }

    .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content b {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
     }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

     .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

     .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #1375b9;}
     </style>
     </head>
     <body>


     <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Family</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a value="http://www.">Victoria</a>
      <a value="http://www.">New South Wales</a>
      <a value="http://www.">Canberra</a>
      <a value="http://www.">Queensland</a>
      <a value="http://www.">Northern Territory</a>
      <a value="http://www.">Western Australia</a>
      <a value="http://www.">South Australia</a>
     </div>
     </div>

     </body>
     </html>
```

I dont know where in the HTML or the CSS i am meant to edit in order to be able to have both of the buttons be different colours i have tried changing the hex values on both of the buttons to different colours but even if they are different they both still appear the same on the page

Comment: What kind of structure is this? there's two HTMLs inside this snippet

Comment: I was not sure how to add two buttons in the same structure i want them all in the same html body but i want to have them as two different colours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you So much for the help learned heaps appreciate the fast and precise help on how to do what I wanted to do with my code many many thanks :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .dropbtn {
      background-color: #459b7a;
      color: white;
      padding: 20px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
    }

    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #459b7a;}

    .colorOil{
      background-color: #c2dd22;
    }
    .colorGray{
      background-color: gray;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>


 <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="dropbtn">Family 2</button>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a value="http://www.">Victoria</a>
     <a value="http://www.">New South Wales</a>
     <a value="http://www.">Canberra</a>
     <a value="http://www.">Queensland</a>
     <a value="http://www.">Northern Territory</a>
     <a value="http://www.">Western Australia</a>
     <a value="http://www.">South Australia</a>
   </div>
 </div>


 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn colorOil">Family</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a value="http://www.">Victoria</a>
    <a value="http://www.">New South Wales</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Canberra</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Queensland</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Northern Territory</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Western Australia</a>
    <a value="http://www.">South Australia</a>
  </div>
</div>

 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn color1">Family</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a value="http://www.">Victoria</a>
    <a value="http://www.">New South Wales</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Canberra</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Queensland</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Northern Territory</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Western Australia</a>
    <a value="http://www.">South Australia</a>
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn colorGray">Family</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a value="http://www.">Victoria</a>
    <a value="http://www.">New South Wales</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Canberra</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Queensland</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Northern Territory</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Western Australia</a>
    <a value="http://www.">South Australia</a>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .dropbtn {
      background-color: #459b7a;
      color: white;
      padding: 20px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
    }

    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #459b7a;}

    .colorOil{
      background-color: #c2dd22;
    }
    .colorGray{
      background-color: gray;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>


 <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="dropbtn">Family 2</button>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a value="http://www.">Victoria</a>
     <a value="http://www.">New South Wales</a>
     <a value="http://www.">Canberra</a>
     <a value="http://www.">Queensland</a>
     <a value="http://www.">Northern Territory</a>
     <a value="http://www.">Western Australia</a>
     <a value="http://www.">South Australia</a>
   </div>
 </div>


 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn colorOil">Family</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a value="http://www.">Victoria</a>
    <a value="http://www.">New South Wales</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Canberra</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Queensland</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Northern Territory</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Western Australia</a>
    <a value="http://www.">South Australia</a>
  </div>
</div>

 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn color1">Family</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a value="http://www.">Victoria</a>
    <a value="http://www.">New South Wales</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Canberra</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Queensland</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Northern Territory</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Western Australia</a>
    <a value="http://www.">South Australia</a>
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn colorGray">Family</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a value="http://www.">Victoria</a>
    <a value="http://www.">New South Wales</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Canberra</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Queensland</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Northern Territory</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Western Australia</a>
    <a value="http://www.">South Australia</a>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    .dropbtn {
    background-color: #459b7a;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    }

    .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
      }

      .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      }

     .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

     .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

     .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #459b7a;}
     </style>
     </head>
     <body>


     <div class="dropdown">
     <button class="dropbtn">Family 2</button>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a value="http://www.">Victoria</a>
     <a value="http://www.">New South Wales</a>
     <a value="http://www.">Canberra</a>
     <a value="http://www.">Queensland</a>
     <a value="http://www.">Northern Territory</a>
      <a value="http://www.">Western Australia</a>
     <a value="http://www.">South Australia</a>
     </div>
     </div>

     </body>
     </html>
 
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <style>
     .dropbtn {
     background-color: #1375b9;
     color: white;
     padding: 20px;
     font-size: 16px;
     border: none;
     }

     .dropdown {
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
     }

    .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content b {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
     }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

     .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

     .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #1375b9;}
     </style>
     </head>
     <body>


     <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Family</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a value="http://www.">Victoria</a>
      <a value="http://www.">New South Wales</a>
      <a value="http://www.">Canberra</a>
      <a value="http://www.">Queensland</a>
      <a value="http://www.">Northern Territory</a>
      <a value="http://www.">Western Australia</a>
      <a value="http://www.">South Australia</a>
     </div>
     </div>

     </body>
     </html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .dropbtn {
      background-color: #459b7a;
      color: white;
      padding: 20px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
    }

    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #459b7a;}

    .colorOil{
      background-color: #c2dd22;
    }
    .colorGray{
      background-color: gray;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>


 <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="dropbtn">Family 2</button>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a value="http://www.">Victoria</a>
     <a value="http://www.">New South Wales</a>
     <a value="http://www.">Canberra</a>
     <a value="http://www.">Queensland</a>
     <a value="http://www.">Northern Territory</a>
     <a value="http://www.">Western Australia</a>
     <a value="http://www.">South Australia</a>
   </div>
 </div>


 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn colorOil">Family</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a value="http://www.">Victoria</a>
    <a value="http://www.">New South Wales</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Canberra</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Queensland</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Northern Territory</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Western Australia</a>
    <a value="http://www.">South Australia</a>
  </div>
</div>

 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn color1">Family</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a value="http://www.">Victoria</a>
    <a value="http://www.">New South Wales</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Canberra</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Queensland</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Northern Territory</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Western Australia</a>
    <a value="http://www.">South Australia</a>
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn colorGray">Family</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a value="http://www.">Victoria</a>
    <a value="http://www.">New South Wales</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Canberra</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Queensland</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Northern Territory</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Western Australia</a>
    <a value="http://www.">South Australia</a>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .dropbtn {
      background-color: #459b7a;
      color: white;
      padding: 20px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
    }

    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #459b7a;}

    .colorOil{
      background-color: #c2dd22;
    }
    .colorGray{
      background-color: gray;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>


 <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="dropbtn">Family 2</button>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a value="http://www.">Victoria</a>
     <a value="http://www.">New South Wales</a>
     <a value="http://www.">Canberra</a>
     <a value="http://www.">Queensland</a>
     <a value="http://www.">Northern Territory</a>
     <a value="http://www.">Western Australia</a>
     <a value="http://www.">South Australia</a>
   </div>
 </div>


 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn colorOil">Family</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a value="http://www.">Victoria</a>
    <a value="http://www.">New South Wales</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Canberra</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Queensland</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Northern Territory</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Western Australia</a>
    <a value="http://www.">South Australia</a>
  </div>
</div>

 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn color1">Family</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a value="http://www.">Victoria</a>
    <a value="http://www.">New South Wales</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Canberra</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Queensland</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Northern Territory</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Western Australia</a>
    <a value="http://www.">South Australia</a>
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn colorGray">Family</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a value="http://www.">Victoria</a>
    <a value="http://www.">New South Wales</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Canberra</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Queensland</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Northern Territory</a>
    <a value="http://www.">Western Australia</a>
    <a value="http://www.">South Australia</a>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need to also add a margin between buttons would this be the code i should use ?               <button style="margin:5px;">Button 1</button>

Comment: Add margin-right:5px to .dropdown{}

Comment: Hi @zac7878 consider accepting this answer by clicking the check mark if this is the most suitable answer :D